# Xamarin iOS: Check if notification sound is enabled

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I'm attempting to find out if the user has sound/vibration on for notifications in the iOS settings. I'm using Xamarin forms but Xamarin.iOS would be acceptable as well.

It seems like its something like
UIUserNotificationSettings.GetSettingsForTypes(UIUserNotificationType.Sound, new NSSet());
but I'm unsure what to do with the NSSet to read the setting after.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `UserNotifications.framework` was added in iOS 10 and replaced `UIUserNotification`.

You can use `UNUserNotificationCenter` to determine what is enabled:

```
var notificationSettings = await UNUserNotificationCenter.Current.GetNotificationSettingsAsync();
switch (notificationSettings.SoundSetting)
{
    case UNNotificationSetting.Disabled:
        break;
    case UNNotificationSetting.Enabled:
        break;
    case UNNotificationSetting.NotSupported; // Simulator...
        break;
}
```

Comment: This code will throw an exception is any iOS below 10 so be sure to catch it!